# Extract all attributes values with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, extract

Can anybody help? I have following XML:

```
<root>
 <tag1 attr="something1">
    <tag21 attr="something21"></tag21>
    <tag321 attr="something321"></tag321>
 </tag1>
 <tag144 attr="something15">
    <tag21 attr="something215"></tag21>
     <tag321 attr="something32156"></tag321>
 </tag144>
</root>
```

Basicly i would need to write every value of attr in new XML like:

```
something1
somethin21
something321
something15
something215
something 32156
```

I tried everything, but can not make it work like i would need to. Also note that attr can  appear everywhere in XML (not just XML structure and nodes above).

Thanks for all your help,
Eoglasi

Comment: select="//@*" should do it

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//@attr" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@attr">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
something1
something21
something321
something15
something215
something32156
```

Here is an XSLT that uses grouping to only show distinct values.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:key name="kAttr" match="@attr" use="." />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates 
      select="//@attr[generate-id() = 
                      generate-id(key('kAttr', .)[1])] " />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@attr">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is good answer, but now i found out that i have duplicate values. Can it be done like above, but to remove also duplicate values so only one unique value would be in result? Thanks for help, Eoglasi

Comment: @eoglasi I know this is an old question, but I just noticed your comment. I have added an XSLT above that only shows unique values.